# Using React-Native Cli, how to use constants etc. other expo dependent things?

Tags: react-native, mobile, constants, expo, react-native-cli

So due to some issues, we starteed project without expo but now every other tutorial shows expo, it uses constants or icons from expo, how to use them?

Answer (score 0):

you can install follow these instructions: https://docs.expo.io/bare/hello-world/
alternatively, init your project with `expo init` and choose a "bare" template - this is the same as a project created with react-native CLI but with expo modules set up.